# Splitting a string into chunks using recursion

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to split a string of arbitrary length into chunks of 3 characters.  I know this question has been asked previously ([How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)), but that answer solves the problem with a list comprehension; I'm trying to solve the problem using a recursive function call, so my question is more about recursive functions calls in Python.

My function works fine until the "base case", the very last string of 3 or less characters.  I am getting a `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list`.

Why is the base case returning `None` instead of a `list`? I explicitly create a list called `final_value` in the base case and return that. I even have a debugging print statement that shows me that the base case return value is of type `<class 'list'>`.

My code is below.

```
three_char_strings = []

def split3(str):
    if len(str) <= 3:
        final_value = []
        final_value.append(str)
        print('Final value: %s\nFinal value type: %s\n' % (final_value, type(final_value))) #For debugging
        return final_value
    else:
        beginning = str[0:3]
        three_char_strings.append(beginning)
        remaining = str[3:]
        three_char_strings + split3(remaining)
```

Comment: Your recursive function only actually `return`s in the base case - it needs to do it in both.

Comment: Yes I see that now and I need to fix that.  Thank you.  But that still doesn't fix the problem of why the base case is returning a "NoneType".

Comment: The base case isn't, **the other case is** (without an explicit `return` you get `None` back by default).

Comment: You're right.  I edited it and added a return statement in the recursive part.  I no longer get any error.  However, the final string from the base case is not being added to my list.  For example, `splits3('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')` returns  ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx'].  The final string 'yz' is not being added to the list.

Comment: Writing a recursive function that uses a global variable is a bad idea. Consider what happens if you call it twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You **only** `return` in the base case, so the other case will implicitly `return None`; and
2. You don't mutate `three_char_strings` in the base case. In fact, it's not clear why you would implement this to mutate an external list *at all*, as this will cause problems if you need to call it again.

You should probably have done something like:

```
def split3(str):
    if len(str) <= 3:
        return [str]
    else:
        beginning = str[:3]
        remaining = str[3:]
        return [beginning] + split3(remaining)
```

Which does what you want, *without* relying on the `three_char_list` list to be in-scope and empty when the function is called:

```
>>> split3('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz']
```

---

The downside of that approach is that it creates several lists. If you want one list per top-level call, you could do e.g.:

```
def split3(str, out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = []
    out.append(str[:3])
    if len(str) > 3:
        split3(str[3:], out)
    return out
```

If you're wondering why `out=None`, see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761).

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't figure out how to do it without a global list.  I just didn't know enough.  Now I do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Though the original issue was that your non-base-case didn't have a `return` statement (meaning it implicitly returned `None`), it's also instructive to see how the code could be simplified in Python

```
def split3(s):
    return [s] if len(s) <= 3 else [s[:3]] + split3(s[3:])
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. F.  This is the more elegant Pythonic solution of course, and I will use it in the future.  I didn't check your response as "the answer" because I really wanted to get into the weeds of my recursive function.